# How to disable the "About the new look | Send feedback" popup permanently in Gmail?

Tags: gmail

It's the one being shown on the bottom right.

[image]

Keeps coming when I visit Gmail after closing the popup. Is it possible to disable it permanently?

Answer (score 3):

Someone has [created a userscript to remove](http://userscripts.org/scripts/show/117468) the notification bar.

According to a [discussion on Google Groups](http://www.google.com/support/forum/p/gmail/thread?tid=6af0c14f39e20c23&hl=en) the behaviour of the popup is intended. The popup will be removed 14 days after you have started using the new look.

> We wanted that link to be available to you for the first couple of
>   weeks that they were using the new look so that you could easily
>   access some info about the changes and send us feedback. You can
>   dismiss it per session by hitting the "X" (but it will come back on
>   the next reload, and we will remove it completely 14 days after you
>   first started using the new look.